# Trying to make a pseudo-code to apply to pandas using conditions with columns that are not unique

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to StackOverflow, python, and pandas and I am exploring just the thought process of coding. I never asked a question here, so I am sorry if I messed up the format of asking the question.

My scenario is that I have a list of products, as a data frame, and I merged it with another table (join) called ordered_products using product_ID as the mutual key.

**My question for this data set is How many orders have only organic produce?**
Now when someone orders groceries, one order_ID can have multiple entries.

I am trying to write a loop Pseudo-code:

```
counter = 0
break the table to group by order_id
For each group{
    For each index within the group{
         If (name of product) has the word "organic"
                {x = true}
         else
                {x = false}
    }
    If x = true,
         {add 1 to counter}
}
```

The counter at the end should be the total amount of unique order_id's that only had "organic" produce.

Example:

```
Order_id | Name           | 
1          organic bread
1          organic beans
1          regular milk
2          organic milk
2          organic lettuce
3          regular orange
3          regular bread

Output: counter = 1
```

For some reason, I just can't figure it out or even apply it to become code!
I hope this makes sense! If anyone can help, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I think you should provide sample data and expected output rather than pseudo code.

Comment: What's your sample output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
counter = df['Name'].str.contains('organic').groupby(df['Order_id']).all().sum()
print (counter)
1
```

Details with explanation:

Tirst test by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) if matching  `organic` - output is boolean mask:

```
print (df['Name'].str.contains('organic'))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
Name: Name, dtype: bool
```

Then use [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) for check if all `True`s per groups:

```
print (df['Name'].str.contains('organic').groupby(df['Order_id']).all())
Order_id
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: Name, dtype: bool
```

Last count number of `True`s by `sum`:

```
counter = df['Name'].str.contains('organic').groupby(df['Order_id']).all().sum()
print (counter)
1
```

Or another aprioach is get all `Order_id` if not contains `organic` values by `~` for invert mask and then subtract sets with check their length:

```
groups = df.loc[~df['Name'].str.contains('organic'), 'Order_id']
counter = len(set(df['Order_id']) - set(groups))
print (counter)
1
```

Comment: for the str.contains(), should I use: flags = re.IGNORECASE?

Comment: @jay.tanti - sure, it is possible. Or also `.str.contains('organic', flags=re.I)` for less typing ;)

Comment: Wow, there is so much to learn. So I ran the code, and it worked. Your explanation made me understand it much easier. The syntax for pandas is still a bit confusing for me. But thank you very much!